# if statement comparing integers not working in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

I am trying to perform logic based on the values of two integers. Here I am defining my integers, and I also have NSLog so I can see if the values are correct when I run the code:

```
int theHikeFlag = (int)[theNewHikeFlag objectAtIndex:(theID-1)];
NSLog(@"theHikeFlag: %@",theHikeFlag);
int fromTheDB = [self.detailItem hikeFlag];
NSLog(@"fromTheDB: %d",fromTheDB);
```

And here is the logic:

```
if (theHikeFlag==1) {
    hikeString=@"You have";
}
else if (theHikeFlag==0) {
    hikeString=@"You have not";
}
else {
    if (fromTheDB==1) {
        hikeString=@"You have";
    }
    else {
        hikeString=@"You have not";
    }
}
```

As an example of how this code is working. When `theHikeFlag=1` and `fromTheDB=0`, the code bypasses the if and the else if and goes straight to the else and sets `hikeString="You have not"`. This means that my result is irrelevant of theHikeFlag and is based on the fromTheDB integer.

Comment: if `theNewHikeFlag` is an `NSArray` those things stored in there are `NSObject*`s you should not be casting them to basic data types.  If they are stored as `NSNumber*`s, cast them as such, and then take `intValue`

Comment: Can you show me the log output you are getting while running all the possible test cases? I have a feeling something weird is happening when you (int) cast whatever is in theNewHikeFlag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot store `int`s in an array, the line

```
(int)[theNewHikeFlag objectAtIndex:(theID-1)];
```

is not doing what you think it should. You need to pull the data from `NSNumber`, not cast to `int`.

```
int theHikeFlag = [[theNewHikeFlag objectAtIndex:(theID-1)] intValue];
```

The reason why the log output is correct is a bit funny: you made two mistakes in a row! First, you re-interpreted a pointer as an `int`, and then you let `NSLog` re-interpret it as an object again by adding a format specifier `%@` that is incompatible with `int`, but works fine with pointers! Since the `int` value contains a pointer to `NSNumber`, `NSLog` produces the "correct" output.

Comment: Nice solution ! Thank you. I tried casting the value to (NSInteger), (int) and even (BOOL); non of them worked.